# Why is it possible, that count of tables more than MaxNoOfTables in mysql ndb cluster?

Tags: mysql

I use mysql ndb cluster 7.5.13 and set MaxNoOfTables=1024, but I have more than 2000 tables in my ndb cluster. All these tables have ENGINE ndbcluster.
Why is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :

> - MaxNoOfTables
>
> A table object is allocated for each table and for each unique hash index in the cluster. This parameter sets a suggested maximum number of table objects for the cluster as a whole; like MaxNoOfAttributes, it is not intended to function as a hard upper limit.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxnooftables

Comment: Okey. But how can I understand what is my upper limit, if MaxNoOfTables is not upper limit?

Comment: @Alexandr  This answered the question that was asked. It seems like your comment above is asking a *different* question.  "Given MaxNoOfTables is not a hard upper limit on the number of tables   Q: what parameters/factors set/affect the hard limit, and Q: is there a way to determine what that upper limit is."  Then go on to describe the number of tables in the NDB cluster, ...  new questions should be posted as a *question*, not as a comment on an answer.